# How to show border corners when a border is hidden

Tags: html, css

So, I have a div for which three sides are shown and the bottom border is set to none. However, I'd like to keep the bottom left and right corners visible. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code or own work so you get proper answer. To the point.

Comment: The only relevant css was basically this:

`#content{border:solid;border-bottom:none;}`

However, someone posted a working solution below.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css styles

```
<html>
<div id="test" >something </div>
</html>

<style>
#test {
border-top-style: hidden;
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-left-style:solid;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 .test {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom-left-radius:1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:1px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native css support for this type of effect.  Setting a border style will affect the entire length of that border.  A very creative answer was given here [CSS - show only corner border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border). You will need to modify it to fit your liking, but the basis is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have corner shaped borders two approaches come to mind.

1. use [border image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)
2. use absolutely positioned inner divs to create the affect

[Demo of #2](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/sUJaL/)

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom-left, .bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom-left {
    left: 0;
}

.bottom-right {
    right: 0;
}
```