# Box with darkened corners without using images

Tags: css

Is it possible to recreate a box like this without using background images and only one element?

[image]

Ideally, I'd be able to control which corners are darkened by adding a class, so the above image might be `class="box dark-top dark-left dark-bottom dark-right"`. I can darken two by using :before and :after, but am having problems thinking of a good way to darken three or four corners without adding additional markup.

Comment: `only one element`? Why do you think such an element exists? This kind of box is not really interesting enough to make it standard, we have to use a complex way (like the use of :before and :after as you mentioned). BTW, if there is an element for this, it should have some controls over how dark the corner is, how long the darkness is stretched, which corner is darkened, even the color, ... But is that complex added element really necessary while you can create it (as you mentioned by using :before, :after)? I think such an element won't never be supported.

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys, I added the solution below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666661/142486. @pravin's suggestion put me on the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666278/142486. I should have noted that there would be at least one element inside these boxes, which may have led to the answer quicker. Thanks all!

Comment: what's wrong with @andi's response in [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666193/2037924](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666193/2037924)? I'm not their friend or something, but from a perspective of the question, it looks like the correct answer to me... just curious...

Comment: @andi's is correct, and I marked it as such. I should've specified that there would always be an inner element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to darken all four corners with one element, though I haven't figured out how to darken specific corners yet.  But my theory was to have the original border as the dark border, and then /lighten/ the sides of the box with pseudo-elements.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KZSLH/

```
.box {width:236px; height:236px; border:1px solid #333; position:relative;}
.box:before {content:""; display:block; width:200px; height:236px; position:absolute; top:-1px; left:18px; border-top:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
.box:after {content:""; display:block; width:236px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:18px; left:-1px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's far from perfect, but this is the only way I could think of to do something like that... You'll want to play around with the border thickness, border radius and which borders are rounded to really have it suit your needs

The only thing I couldn't figure out is how to get the edges of the corners to be sharp rather than tapering off... Maybe someone could contribute that part?

First, start off with two overlapping `div` elements:

```
<div id="thick" />
<div id="thin" />
```

Then, use rounded corners and relative positioning to taper off and create the "bold" corners.

```
#thick {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:white;
  border:3px solid black;
}

#thin {
  position:relative;
  top:-2px;
  left:-2px;
  height:104px;
  width:104px;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bGrdA/

And credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border) for giving me the idea.

Comment: looks like the OP wishes for a one-element solution, interesting.

Comment: @KingKing Ah, you're right, I missed the "one element" part... Oh well, I'll leave this up just in case someone else finds it useful down the road...

Comment: well, in fact I think this answer is also helpful (+1) , and the one-element solution is not ideal unless I misunderstood the OP :)

Comment: from this perspective every answer here is useful and could be voted up, provided the end result looks like the OP's image...

Comment: @webeno As long as it's useful to somebody, I think it's a good answer. I'm sure someone else out there will want to create the same visual effect but not have the one element restriction and may stumble upon this thread.

Comment: @DrydenLong then why haven't you voted up all the other answers? :)

Comment: Here is the one-element solution based on your idea which has a little different effect (I prefer to this effect) http://jsfiddle.net/bGrdA/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. The key is that there must be content inside of the box in it's own element, which will always be the case my scenario.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7pgP/

The classes that can be added to the box are:

```
dtl = darken top left
dtr = darken top right
dbl = darken bottom left
dbr = darken bottom right
```

Comment: dude, that's still 2 elements, you have the p in the div :) the correct one is this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666193/2037924](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22666193/2037924)

Comment: True. I marked it correct since I didn't specify that there would be an inner element.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing this can be tried out for two elements

http://jsfiddle.net/V8jmR/

```
#content {position:relative;width:400px;height:300px;}
#content:before, #content:after, #content>:first-child:before, #content>:first-child:after {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px; height: 80px;
    border-color:red; /* or whatever colour */
    border-style:solid; /* or whatever style */
    content: ' ';
}
#content:before {top:0;left:0;border-width: 1px 0 0 1px}
#content:after {top:0;right:0;border-width: 1px 1px 0 0}
#content>:first-child:before {bottom:0;right:0;border-width: 0 1px 1px 0}
#content>:first-child:after {bottom:0;left:0;border-width: 0 0 1px 1px}
```

Original answer 
[CSS - show only corner border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border)

Comment: well, that's still 2 elements, you have the p inside your div :)

Comment: Oops you are correct its with two elements Sorry Corrected

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I know is in using additional elements:

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="darkTopLeft"></span>
    <span class="darkTopRight"></span>
    <span class="darkBottomLeft"></span>
    <span class="darkBottomRight"></span>
</div>

.box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.box > span {
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
}

.darkTopLeft {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}

.darkTopRight {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    right: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}

.darkBottomLeft {
    bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    left: -1px;
}

.darkBottomRight {
    bottom: -1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    right: -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cM7xU/