# CSS Multiple gradient glow from border

Tags: css

Hello I would like to made similar design like [this](http://content.eveonline.com/www/newssystem/media/66657/1/5.png) with CSS.

I've tried to make it with pseudo elements which are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452956/color-border-in-corners-seperatly/24453271#24453271).
I run into a problem every time - with only one gradient box-shadow avaiable or unable to set glowing outline/border separately to every spot.
I have also tried to block glowing outline with help of the eliptic gradient :(

Can someone tell me if is there some unique aproach to this?

There is my [code](http://codepen.io/AlennGK/pen/zNNbrY?editors=1100)

```
.wrap{
  height: 20em;
  width: 15em;
  background: black;
}
.btn-t {
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, blue, blue);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #7B9DFF;
  color: $white-txt;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 3.75em;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.btn-t:after {
  content: '';
    position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
 }


.btn-t:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px white;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #71B1F5, blue);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ This may be useful for your project.

Comment: I am aware of this tool, but I can't set it outside the border for the glowing efect on two diferent places.

Comment: Also I have gradient in place, but I am using sass so it is looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/bTVtcVA.gif

Comment: There are several buttons there in that page. Which one are you trying to make?

Comment: First default and hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a go at reproducing something close (one version for the text buttons, one for the icon version):

Icon version assumes FontAwesome is used to generate the icon (hence the `.fa` references):

```
/* text button */
.btn-glow {
  border: 1px solid #354a40;
  background-color: #1e2120;
  padding: .5em .85em;
  transition: all 0.025s linear;
  color: #6c8678;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.btn-glow:hover {
  color: #e6fcf5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1em #66977b;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
}
.btn-glow:focus {
  color: #79c6a1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  outline: none;
}
.btn-glow:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2em #9ee6bf;
  background-color: #406552;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 100%);
}

/* icon version */
.btn-glow-large {
  border: 1px solid #354a40;
  background-color: #1e2120;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.025s linear;
}
.btn-glow-large .fa {
  color: #6c8678;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: all 0.025s linear;
}
.btn-glow-large:hover {
  border-image: linear-gradient(#375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
}
.btn-glow-large:hover .fa {
  color: #e6fcf5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1em #66977b;
}
.btn-glow-large:focus {
  border-image: linear-gradient(#375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  outline: none;
}
.btn-glow-large:focus .fa {
  color: #79c6a1;
}
.btn-glow-large:active {
  background-color: #406552;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#375345, #9afdcf, #375345) 10;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 100%);
}
.btn-glow-large:active .fa {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2em #9ee6bf;
}
```

See https://codepen.io/ablewhite/pen/gWRQLN?editors=1100#0

Comment: Damn this looks neat .-) Left css for while but this is awesome thank you! Biggest problem for me was setting border-image separated for left/right and top/bottom, but looks good even with one of the sides.