# css & html : Hide corner of the borders

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have following UI. I want to hide only corner of the div of three colors.

it should be look like something this.

```
 _
| |
 -
```

[image]

Can Anyone has idea how to hide the corners of the div borders.

Here is my code as asked for

**html :-**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row container-row green-border">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>                              
        </div>                              
    </div>                              
</div>
```

**Css :-**

```
.container {
    border: 5px solid white; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px orange;
}
.green-border {
    border: 5px solid green; 
}
```

Other css is picking up from bootstrap css.

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: you mean round-shaped ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border
This could be a good idea, but you'll have to adapt it to your case. Or just place a small white backgorund div at each corner.

Comment: So many downvotes? is this question that bad?

Comment: @SachinKanungo It is completely ununderstable to me. "hide the corner of the div borders", what exactly is what he wants? This question would be unanswerable even if he had provided his code.

Comment: Why so many down votes. Is my question is wrong or my client requirement is technically impossible. or you people who have given down votes has less knowledge.

Comment: @vishal-mote: The question is not very clear as it stands. It would help if you clean up your question, explaining clearly what you want, along with what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is little messy, dirty, but it will give desired result.

```css
#container
{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:10px;
}
#tl, #tr, #bl, #br
{
    position:absolute;
    width:10px; height:10px;
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
}
#tl {top:-1px; left:-1px;} /*top left corner*/
#tr {top:-1px; right:-1px;} /*top right*/
#bl {bottom:-1px; left:-1px;} /*bottom left*/
#br {bottom:-1px; right:-1px;} /*bottom right */
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="tl"></div>   
    <div id="tr"></div>
    <div id="bl"></div>
    <div id="br"></div>
    Hello there
</div>
```

But, point is: `background-color` of page, container `div` and that `divs` for corners must be same color.

There is [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/affezr0g/1/) so adding `border` for those "corners" You'll see how it's working.

You have to pay attention for `padding` for `container`; positioning and `height` and `width` for those corners.

Update : I made just little changes about positioning, `height` and `width` of corner `divs`. Old one take too much space out of container `div`.

btw. You can remove `height` for `container`. I set it just for example.