# How to remove some part of borders from the corners?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, corner-detection

I want to remove the corners of borders like this picture.

[image: What I need to draw]

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: where are code ? what is tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css & html : Hide corner of the borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426718/css-html-hide-corner-of-the-borders)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to cover (and thus, "hide") parts of the border:

```css
.bordery {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.bordery::after,
.bordery::before {
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
}
.bordery::after {
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
}
.bordery::before {
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordery">This is just some sample content.</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to create this.

```css
.el {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
}
.el:after,
.el:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
.el:before {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-top: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: 1px solid orange;
}
.el:after {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you're missing the top left + bottom right ones. (EDIT: Oh, wow, nevermind, this is just a nice solution, upvoted)

Comment: Nice approach (quite similar to the one I suggested), but this has the problem of the pseudo elements "covering" the content of the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css3 `linear-gradient` to draw this background to just a single `<div>` element and without using any pseudo elements.

```
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to top, transparent 20px, orange 20px);
  background-position: 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 1px, 1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;      
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 20px, orange 20px),
                    linear-gradient(to top, transparent 20px, orange 20px);
  background-position: 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 1px, 1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following:

```
        #rectangle{
        width:400px;
        height: 200px;
        border-style: solid;
        color:orange;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #eraser1{
    position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:white;
        margin: -10px 0px 0px 374px;
    }
    #eraser2{
    position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:white;
        margin: 175px 0px 0px -13px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clip-path` property to clip corner

```css
div{
    width: 15em;
    height: 5em;
    border: 2px solid red;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 91% 0, 100% 12%, 100% 100%, 12% 100%, 0 89%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```