# Pixel art style border on tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, border, pixel, tumblr

I'm wanted to create a pixel art style border around my #wrap - basically just the corners of the border cut off like this:

[image: Pixilated border]

I'm having a hard time figuring it out (I'm a total beginner when it comes to css and html, and mostly just use it to tweak my tumblr website). This is what the current code and border on the website looks like:

```
        #wrap {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background: #fff;
        background: rgb(225, 225, 225);
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
        border: 5px solid #000;
    }
```

[image: Normal border]

Does anyone know how I can implement this? I thought it'd be easy just to remove the corners of a border, but I can't find any guidance online.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove some part of borders from the corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803132/how-to-remove-some-part-of-borders-from-the-corners)

Comment: Hi fraggley, Paulie_D below solved my problem. Thanks for the input thought!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use multiple `box-shadow`

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 2em auto;
  box-shadow:   -15px 0 0 0 black,
                 15px 0 0 0 black,
                 0 -15px 0 0 black,
                 0 15px 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, Paulie_D! I'm very grateful for your quick and simple fix. Thanks again!