# Hide part of div border

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to hide some portion of div border using css , to be more specific Border of ngb accordion panrl,
I have border for left side and Bottom I want to hide 5%  from the start and end of left border and 10% from start and end of bottom border.

below is the image to clarify more on what I am trying to achieve
I am tying to hide the area marked by the red boxes.

any help with css for this is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css & html : Hide corner of the borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426718/css-html-hide-corner-of-the-borders)

Comment: @sulox32 I looked at the answer to the question you mentioned, adding 4 extra <div> manually for borders is not a good idea, the answer to this question seems a decent approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use ::before and ::after pseudo elements

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.yourdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.yourdiv::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.yourdiv::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourdiv">Your div</div>
```