# Creating a stroked frame effect with css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a design with this effect

[image]

**I dont care about the font styles or any details, all i am focused right now is on the creating the frame and if possible the button as well.** Does anyone know how to do this kind of effect in css?

Here is my very basic html/css code, wont even be of any help. And you can completely modify it if it suits better. BTW i am using bootstrap 3.

```
/******** The html *********/
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-img">
        <div>Italy has never been so close</div>
    </div>

/******** The css *********/
    .bg-img {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #999 url("http://p1.pichost.me/i/15/1380265.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
    }

    .bg-img div {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    width:10px;
      font-weight:700;
    }
```

I am using a generic image, as it shouldn't make any difference. Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/3aL4xnr8/

Comment: Is it important for the stroke to have a variable width, from thick to thin? If so, using a border image may be the way to go: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border/33106451#33106451 (not closing as dupe because this needs the effect only on two corners).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) and [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-elements.

```css
div {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 40px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect :), is there any way to have the stroke as well on the borders?

Comment: Thank you everybody for taking the time to get this working :)