# React Native broken up border

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, border

I am looking for some styling guidance for React-Native. I am wanting to create a border that only has a certain amount of the corners colored. Something like this:
[image]

I currently have this:
[image]

```js
  captureSquare: {
    height: 450,
    width: 450,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

I am not sure how to break up the borders. Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to think that this can be achieved using a CSS `border-image` but I can't work out how!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - show only corner border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do this by adding 4 `<View />`s to the captureSqaure and giving them the following properties:

```js
  topLeftEdge: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF,
    borderLeftWidth: 3,
    borderTopWidth: 3,
  },
```

Comment: Do you know how to give radius on corner here ?

Comment: @AjayS I am not 100% positive but you may be able to add `borderTopLeftRadius`, `borderTopRightRadius`, `borderTopEndRadius`, `borderTopStartRadius`, or whatever corner you're wanting to add radius too