# Camera View Corner Borders In Css

Tags: html, css

This is question not more specific. I want to so common, because most of the web developers have this problem.

We all know the camera view which has border in 4 corners but not in the right/left/bottom/top. [image: Like This]

How can we make this effect using css?

html

```
<div id="div1" />
<div id="div2" />
```

css

```
#div1 {
   position:absolute;
   top:9px;
   left:9px;
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
   background-color:white;
   border:1px solid black;
}

#div2 {
  position:relative;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  height:102px;
  width:102px;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I achieved it like this.Now I want to know how can achieve this using only one `div`

Comment: You want to apply 4 white corners? show us what you tried so far

Comment: you can use this link : https://divi-sensei.com/blog/2017/08/15/create-edge-corner-border-border-css-pimp-images/

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: @Saboor This helps. Thank you ;-)

Comment: you copy from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border but `<div id="div2"></div>` NOT  `<div id="div2" />`

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050006/css-border-on-corners-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Border on Corners Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050006/css-border-on-corners-only)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should use parent->child logic
For example :

```
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

EXAMPLE : 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Developergurkan/pen/wxmVmp)