# How to make oblique endings of after and before elements?

Tags: css, html

you can see a pic below (I am really bad at painting, sorry for that). I don't know how to make these (I guess) box-shadows (pink in the picture) only on two corners, but their ending is oblique. Because what I think, those borders (red in the picture) on corners can be made with after and before elements. 
What I would do is to make two boxes, one inside the other and add a box shadow. But I stop at that point how to make those oblique endings and how to make those shadows shorter than the whole height or length. Maybe you have any ideas?

[image]

this is what i have tries so far:

```css
.div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px;
}

.div2::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

span::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div class="div2"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: box-shadow won't do this, but a a few linear background will. what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - show only corner border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/css-show-only-corner-border)

Comment: This [pen](https://codepen.io/heyvian/pen/xEovGd) may bring resolution to your issues.

Comment: Those solutions you suggested, I have found myself. But I need not only that. The pink parts of the question is what I don't know how to do.

Comment: I answered you and asked you what you have done so far . have done that linear-gradient i talked about ? did you figure out about background-clip and background-size to pile this few bits together ? box-shadow will not do this :( see what bg can do https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfTYH.jpg

Comment: No, about linear gradient I haven't tried. So, you suggest me to have one box into another. One box with after and before elements and the outter box somehow with background-clip. Ok. I will write code in couplle of minutes.

Comment: a single box and padding is needed for this. one oblique gradient and 1 plain blue and 4 plain red, no pseudo element that you can use for something else .  ;) give it a try and we will help from there. from `<div class="mybox"> My Box</div>` you can get https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfTYH.jpg

Comment: Ok, I will change now this code that I have just written according to your recommendations.

Comment: I have tried to read, but I don't really get it how to do this with gradients...

Comment: Because what I know about gradients is the transition from one color to the other. And here what  I see is few different parts with different colours..

Comment: yes it's no easy when it comes to multiple .. @G-Cyr you can probably add you answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

about gradient see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

> The `linear-gradient()` CSS function creates an image consisting of a progressive transition between two or more colors along a straight line. Its result is an object of the `<gradient>` data type, which is a special kind of `<image>`.

about multiple background https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/
 & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

> You can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back. Only the last background can include a background color.

`background-size` is also usefull here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> The `background-size` CSS property sets the size of the element's background image. The image can be left to its natural size, stretched, or constrained to fit the available space.

`background-clip` comes handy too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

> The background-clip CSS property sets whether an element's background  or  extends underneath its border.

playing around with background-^properties you could do something like this

```css
.mybox {
  width:250px;
  height:180px;
  padding:20px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(237, 28, 36),rgb(237, 28, 36)),
    linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(237, 28, 36),rgb(237, 28, 36)),
    linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(237, 28, 36),rgb(237, 28, 36)),
    linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(237, 28, 36),rgb(237, 28, 36)),
    linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 162, 232), rgb(0, 162, 232)),    
    linear-gradient(-45deg, rgb(255, 174, 201) 20%, rgb(0, 162, 232) 20%, rgb(0, 162, 232) 80%, rgb(255, 174, 201) 80%) ;
  background-clip: border-box, border-box,border-box, border-box, content-box,border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:  3px 40px, 80px 3px, 3px 40px, 80px 3px,auto auto,auto auto;
  background-position: 22px 160px, 22px 200px , 260px 15px  , 180px 15px ,center,  center;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:3rem;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px  10px purple
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox"> My Box</div>
```

Comment: for the background-position I would probably consider the syntax `top/bottom X right/left Y`,  to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Here is my idea using multiple background and `border-image`

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:15px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(-45deg,pink 20%,transparent 20%,transparent 80%,pink 80%) 15;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) top right,
    linear-gradient(red,red) top right, 
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom left, 
    linear-gradient(red,red) bottom left,
    #00a2e8;
  background-size:2px 40px,40px 2px;
  background-origin:padding-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Here is another idea using less gradient:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:15px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(-45deg,pink 20%,transparent 20%,transparent 80%,pink 80%) 15;
  background:#00a2e8;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(30deg,red 20%,transparent 20%,transparent 80%,red 80%) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: PS: wait for the answer of G-Cyr before accepting this one

Comment: Thank you. Never would have done this myself.. So many things to learn :)

Comment: yours is fine, i added some extra gradients to show about background-clip . i wish the op lots of fun with gradients and shadow ;)

Comment: @Tom added another easier method