# HTML + CSS borders and alignment doest work well

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my very first HTML with a little CSS and I have got a sample that I need to recreate but I don't know exatly what I have to do from here.

```css
.chessboard {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 60px;
    text-align:justify;
    
}
.chessboardbelso{
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 60px;
    border: 1pc solid #b38365 ;
    
}
.black {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:#180f0a;
    color: #ede4e0;
    font-size:60px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.white {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:#ede4e0;
    color: black;
    font-size:60px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}

.outsidelefttop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.outsiderighttop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


.outsideleftbottom{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.outsiderightbottom{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}











.outsideleft{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.outsidetop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.outsidereversed{
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center; 
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    
}
.outsidereversedright{
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Chessboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Chess.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="chessboard">
<!--outsidetop-->
<div class="outsidelefttop"></div>
<div class="outsidereversed">H</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">G</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">F</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">E</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">D</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">C</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">B</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">A</div>
<div class="outsiderighttop"></div>


<!--1-->
<div class="outsideleft">8</div>
<div class="black">&#9814;</div>
<div class="white">&#9816;</div>
<div class="black">&#9815;</div>
<div class="white">&#9812;</div>
<div class="black">&#9813;</div>
<div class="white">&#9815;</div>
<div class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div class="white">&#9814;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">1</div>
<!--2-->
<div class="outsideleft">7</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">2</div>
<!--3-->
<div class="outsideleft">6</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">3</div>
<!--4-->
<div class="outsideleft">5</div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">4</div>
<!--5-->
<div class="outsideleft">4</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">5</div>
<!--6-->
<div class="outsideleft">3</div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">6</div>
<!--7-->
<div class="outsideleft">2</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">7</div>
<!--8-->
<div class="outsideleft">1</div>
<div class="white">&#9814;</div>
<div class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div class="white">&#9815;</div>
<div class="black">&#9813;</div>
<div class="white">&#9812;</div>
<div class="black">&#9815;</div>
<div class="white">&#9816;</div>
<div class="black">&#9814;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright">8</div>
<!--outsidelent-->
<div class="outsideleftbottom"></div>
<div class="outsidetop">H</div>
<div class="outsidetop">G</div>
<div class="outsidetop">F</div>
<div class="outsidetop">E</div>
<div class="outsidetop">D</div>
<div class="outsidetop">C</div>
<div class="outsidetop">B</div>
<div class="outsidetop">A</div>
<div class="outsiderightbottom"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to recreate this image and I cant get the number and words in the middle and I don't know how can I make the little missing pieces from the inner-border.

Any recommendation what I have to do to finish it?

**Here is the image**
[image]

Comment: For the missing corner borders [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/how-can-i-show-only-corner-borders).

Answer (score 0):

For centering numbers and letters you can add this code to each container, this will center it's content vertically and horizontally.

```
/* change container to "outsidetop" etc. or add new class in html to each element */
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If you're interested how this works I would recommend reading more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

As for the borders I would abandon you solution with adding border to every outside container and just wrap the chessboard fields in a container with border.

Next time try to be more specific and concise in formulating questions. If you're not sure how to correctly ask questions read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I just added the display:flex; property to make all the numbers align center, and  i added sudo after class for all four outside corner elements to merge the borders. check the css at the end ,and i had  d-flex class to the all number elments, p-rel to all outside corner elements.

here is the output image[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHTun.png)

```css
.chessboard {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 60px;
    text-align:justify;
    
}
.chessboardbelso{
    width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: 60px;
    border: 1pc solid #b38365 ;
    
}
.black {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:#180f0a;
    color: #ede4e0;
    font-size:60px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.white {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color:#ede4e0;
    color: black;
    font-size:60px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}

.outsidelefttop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.outsiderighttop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}


.outsideleftbottom{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.outsiderightbottom{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}











.outsideleft{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.outsidetop{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    
}
.outsidereversed{
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-top: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center; 
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    
}
.outsidereversedright{
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: #b38365 solid 10px;
    border-right: #b38365 solid 10px;
    background-color: #41210a;
    color: #e4e8da;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
    
}

.d-flex{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.p-rel{
    position:relative;
}

.outsideleftbottom::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#b38365;
    z-index:9999999999999;
}
.outsiderightbottom::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#b38365;
    z-index:9999999999999;
}

.outsidelefttop::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#b38365;
    z-index:9999999999999;
}
.outsiderighttop::after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#b38365;
    z-index:9999999999999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Chessboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Chess.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="chessboard">
<!--outsidetop-->
<div class="outsidelefttop p-rel"></div>
<div class="outsidereversed">H</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">G</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">F</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">E</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">D</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">C</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">B</div>
<div class="outsidereversed">A</div>
<div class="outsiderighttop p-rel"></div>


<!--1-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">8</div>
<div class="black">&#9814;</div>
<div class="white">&#9816;</div>
<div class="black">&#9815;</div>
<div class="white">&#9812;</div>
<div class="black">&#9813;</div>
<div class="white">&#9815;</div>
<div class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div class="white">&#9814;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">1</div>
<!--2-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">7</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="white">&#9823;</div>
<div class="black">&#9823;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">2</div>
<!--3-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">6</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">3</div>
<!--4-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">5</div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">4</div>
<!--5-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">4</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">5</div>
<!--6-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">3</div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">6</div>
<!--7-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">2</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="black">&#9817;</div>
<div class="white">&#9817;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">7</div>
<!--8-->
<div class="outsideleft d-flex">1</div>
<div class="white">&#9814;</div>
<div class="black">&#9816;</div>
<div class="white">&#9815;</div>
<div class="black">&#9813;</div>
<div class="white">&#9812;</div>
<div class="black">&#9815;</div>
<div class="white">&#9816;</div>
<div class="black">&#9814;</div>
<div class="outsidereversedright d-flex">8</div>
<!--outsidelent-->

<div class="outsideleftbottom p-rel"></div>
<div class="outsidetop">H</div>
<div class="outsidetop">G</div>
<div class="outsidetop">F</div>
<div class="outsidetop">E</div>
<div class="outsidetop">D</div>
<div class="outsidetop">C</div>
<div class="outsidetop">B</div>
<div class="outsidetop">A</div>
<div class="outsiderightbottom p-rel"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

For the letters and numbers try flex display (there is a clear explanation of flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)):

```
display: flex, #flex direction is "row" by default
justify-content: center, #horizontally center (distributes along the main-axis, which is row)
align-content: center, #vertically center (distributes along the cross-axis, which is column)
```

The little missing pieces could be filled in by specifying borders of the inner corners of the chest board. For example border-left and border-top for the top left chest piece.

Your approach does feel quite repetitive and I would assume they want you to apply the border on the entire chest board and the entire inner chest board.
Take a look at the "DRY principle".

Comment: Care to explain what Display flex does, OP mentioned they are new to html/css? Also why are you wrapping your values in double quotes ("), like `display: "flex";` ??

Comment: @Dejan.S My mistake I've been writing much react lately and css-in-js have quotes.