# How can I restrict a div to the bottom-right corner of its container?

Tags: html, css, containers

So I'm wanting to put a small border around the top-left and bottom-right corner of an image. The top-right one works perfectly fine, but the bottom-right one doesn't seem to anchor itself properly to the bottom right corner of the black container, which affects its thickness.

On the left is what I want it to look like, but on the right is an image when I resize the window.

[image: please see this picture where on the left is what I want it to look like, but on the right is an image when I resize the window.]

```css
.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.container {
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  flex: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  img {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .borders {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .left-corner-border {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2%;
    top: -1.5%;
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .right-corner-border {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 67.5%;
    bottom: -1.5%;
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

.about-us-text {
  padding: 0px 80px 0px 0px;
  flex: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1485px) {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  .column {
    display: flex;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    //background-color: red;
  }
  img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    filter: brightness(1%);
  }
  .borders {
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .about-us-text {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .right-corner-border {
    background-color: red !important;
    left: 69% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="match-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="Lorem Ipsum.">

  <div class="borders">
    <div class="left-corner-border"></div>
    <div class="right-corner-border"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise your snippet to show the problem. Use rendered CSS, not SASS.

Comment: From the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913549/8620333 you can easily remove any side and keep the one you want