# How to add stroke or dashed border to a text using CSS or SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

Am trying to figure out how can I add a dashed border to my header text, such that my result should be as shown in the image below.

**Please see the code I tried (React JSX):**

```
<Box>
    <p className="recentTitle"> Recent Transactions</p>
</Box>
```

**CSS**

```
.recentTitle {
    margin-left: 6% !important;
    margin-top: 7% !important;
    outline: 1px dashed white;
    width: fit-content !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

**The result I want to show or am trying to achieve.**

[image: UI]

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read and comment in advance.

Comment: You could use psuedo-elements to achieve either corner (e.g. make a `::before` with just a top and left border, and position it in the top left corner of the button, then the width and height of the pseudo-element determine the length of the lines). Alternatively, you can give the button a full border, and use a polygonal `clip-path` to cut off bits of the border you don't want to show (since the button looks transparent, this is fairly simple and less verbose than pseudo-elements). Lastly, you might be able to achieve this using `border-image`, though that's probably not the nicest solution.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913549/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a little opportunities for customize border.

But you can use a trick with `::before` and `::after` for imitate border.

```css
body {
background: #000;
}

.recentTitle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
}

.recentTitle::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.recentTitle::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recentTitle"> Recent Transactions</div>
```

Here is one more interesting example with useing pseudo classes:

(original source: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MqMZGR?editors=0010)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.gradient-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 22em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30% 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* !importanté */
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  /* !importanté */
  border-radius: 2em;
}
.gradient-box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: -5px;
  /* !importanté */
  border-radius: inherit;
  /* !importanté */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-box">
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent bibendum, lorem vel tincidunt imperdiet, nibh elit laoreet felis, a bibendum nisl tortor non orci. Donec pretium fermentum felis, quis aliquet est rutrum ut. Integer quis massa ut lacus viverra pharetra in eu lacus. Aliquam tempus odio adipiscing diam pellentesque rhoncus. Curabitur a bibendum est. </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the border on the p in the usual way and then use clip-path to cut out the bits you don't want.

In this snippet it's been assumed that the amount to you want to clip out is equivalent to the 5px padding, but of course you can have a more complex step sort of path if you want to clip more in the y direction.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.recentTitle {
  margin-left: 6%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  border: solid white 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --c: 5px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% var(--c), 100% var(--c), 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 50% calc(100% - var(--c)), 0% calc(100% - var(--c)));
}
```

```html
<p class="recentTitle"> Recent Transactions</p>
```

Comment: Hi, @AHaworth Thanks a million for the wonderful explanation and solution. and sharing how clip-path can be more helpful.  Really appreciated your time, efforts and guidance sir.