# Rounded corners using CSS for generated QR code box

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement wherein I need to change the corners of the QR code capture box to be rounded instead of straight. I am facing difficulty changing it as it is getting generated from the 3rd party library.

How can I apply border radius to the code structure rather than the container?

```html
<body>
  <div id="qr-shaded-region" style="position: absolute;border-width: 9px 100px;border-style: solid;border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);box-sizing: border-box;inset: 0px;border-radius: 79px 67px 96px 76px;">
    <div style="position: absolute;background-color: Red;width: 40px;height: 5px;top: -5px;left: 0px;border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 40px; height: 5px; top: -5px; right: 0px;border-radius: 79px 67px 96 76;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 40px; height: 5px; top: 325px; left: 0px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 40px; height: 5px; top: 325px; right: 0px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 5px; height: 45px; top: -5px; left: -5px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 5px; height: 45px; top: 285px; left: -5px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 5px; height: 45px; top: -5px; right: -5px;"></div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 5px; height: 45px; top: 285px; right: -5px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am also attaching the image for more clarification.
Left one is current qrcode with no rounded corners and right one is the expected behavior with all 4 sides having rounded corners.
Again I want to say I don't want rounded corners for parent div
[image]

Comment: @sajeshNambiar there is not jsfiddle link in this question either

Comment: Not sure but moderator has removed the jsfiddle link

Comment: I think it's inevitable that you're going to have to wrap the qr code in a div. See some solutions here but you'll have to radius the corners a smidge if that's what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/how-can-i-show-only-corner-borders