# How can I make button with cutting edges

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wan't to make this **button** in html/css but I don't know how.

[image: Button Example]

I've tried many things but I did not succeded in anything. This what I got.

```css
.hero-inner_text a{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #993400;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 3px solid #993400;
    border-radius: 40%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-inner_text">
  <a>Join us</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can it be a fake cutout with holes that match the background color? Or do the cutouts need to be fully transparent

Comment: It might be an image. Have you inspected the button on the website?

Comment: @Nick it's not an image on a website. It's on figma.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```css
.box {
  --b: 5px;   /* thickness of the border */
  --c: red;   /* color of the border */
  --w: 20px;  /* width of border */
  --r: 25px;  /* radius */
  

  padding: var(--b); /* space for the border */
  
  position:relative;
  /*Irrelevant code*/  
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-flex;
  font-size:30px;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
}
.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--c,red);
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(  0deg,#000 calc(2*var(--b)),#0000 0) 50% var(--b)/calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) 100% repeat-y,
    linear-gradient(-90deg,#000 calc(2*var(--b)),#0000 0) var(--b) 50%/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) repeat-x,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--c:brown;--w:40px;--b:10px;--r:40px;">
some content
</div>
```

Or maybe you can find what you need here [How can I show only corner borders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/how-can-i-show-only-corner-borders)