# How can you apply a border to only corners of a container in css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to apply a border to only specific corners of a container, similar to the image below. There is a little border at the corner of the summary containers bellow. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: There are a few approaches available, [this previous answer describes quite a few of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/how-can-i-show-only-corner-borders).

Comment: Next time, if you show some codes or snippets that you've tried, it will be easier to get faster answer and upvotes if it's useful for others wanting the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is focusing more on approach than beautiful design or pattern.
The approach is to have:

1. 1x div as item container with relative position
2. 4x div as corners with absolute position at top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left and have them showed their corresponding corner border radius as 1/4 Arc.
3. Remember `border-radius` has 4 values for each corner like `0px 0px 5px 5px` to draw radius only in bottom-right and bottom-left corner, for your 1st top image.

It looks like this at the end:

[image]

The html codes let's say `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Design</h1>

  <div id="reaction" class="item">
    <div id="top-left" class="corner"></div>
    <div id="top-right" class="corner"></div>
    <div id="bottom-right" class="corner"></div>
    <div id="bottom-left" class="corner"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="icon.png" class="icon" />
      <span class="title">Reaction</span>
      <span class="score">80 / 100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS codes `styles.css`:

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 300;
}
#reaction {
  background-color: #ffaaaa70;
}
.corner {
  position: absolute;
}
#reaction .corner {
  background: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff7777;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff7777;
}
#top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff7777;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff7777;
}
#bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff7777;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff7777;
}
#bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff7777;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff7777;
}
.content {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.icon {
  height: 24;
  width: 24;
}
.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#reaction .title {
  color: #ff7777;
}
.score {
  color: '#444444'
}
```

From there you can apply for other items with their own colors, and use appropriate pattern if using CSS framework.

Comment: And you can play with negative absolute position like `top: -1px; left: -1px;` to get the arc move half outside of the item container. You can shorter arc with `#reaction .corner {` and `height: 6px; width: 6px`.

Answer (score -1):

border-radius:0px 0px 30px 30px;

first value applies to top-left corner, second value applies to top-right corner, third value applies to bottom-right corner, and fourth value applies to bottom-left corner.

Comment: I think the contributor asking the question wants to know how to apply a border to an element with a rounded corner, not how to apply rounded corners. If you look a the element containing the text 'Visual', for example, you'll see there's a very small dark rounded border that's only applied to the rounded edge of the element.

Comment: @adam - Got you. Maybe this could help. https://playcode.io/1249580

Answer (score -1):

border-bottom-right-radius: 25px ;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;

You can write it in a single line.

border-radius:0px 0px 25px 25px;

To set different values for each corner, use the following syntax

border-radius: top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left;