# How can I show only some corner borders on Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, border

For the long 2 days I'm trying to put some corner borders around pictures and text boxes in my wife website. Could you guys know a easy way to do that?

Today I am trying using this:

```
.wp-block-uagb-image {
    position: relative;
}


.wp-block-uagb-image::before {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -12px; 
    right: -2%; 
    width: 2px; 
    height: calc(50% + 20px); 
    background-color: #000; 
    z-index: 2; 
}


.wp-block-uagb-image::after {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -2%; 
    right: -11px; 
    width: calc(50% + 20px);
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

But that way I am suffering to put the lines together, plus, it is changing a lot when I am going to mobile version!

[website top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Hsv.png)

That is the website that I am trying to do it. The idea is to follow the id of the logo with the thin line. That's why I would like to add it also in the bottom left corner too of the text box, for example!

(For some reason the borders are appearing on the footer too! :(

Thank you in advance!

I tried to from a stackoverflow topic:

```
img {
  --s: 50px; /* the size on the corner */
  --t: 5px;  /* the thickness of the border */
  --g: 20px; /* the gap between the border and image */
  
  padding: calc(var(--g) + var(--t));
  outline: var(--t) solid #B38184; /* the color here */
  outline-offset: calc(-1*var(--t));
  -webkit-mask:
    conic-gradient(at var(--s) var(--s),#0000 75%,#000 0)
    0 0/calc(100% - var(--s)) calc(100% - var(--s)),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box;
}
```

link: [How can I show only corner borders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387690/how-can-i-show-only-corner-borders)

but I can't understand the mask!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14387690/2518285) you linked to has many suggested solutions of varying quality. The answer I prefer is [the one by @RobertKirsz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47832651/2518285), and it suits your requirements perfectly.

```css
:root {
  --pbw: 2px;
}
.cb {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left, black var(--pbw), transparent var(--pbw)) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black var(--pbw), transparent var(--pbw)) 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.cb>img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="cb">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/220/150">
</span>
```

Comment: Perfect! You saved me! Thank you so much!